# Full Text Search using Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've been looking through [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) for a while now but I'm wondering if I could do a search by a field instead?

I have my index for my collection set up but in my collection, I have fields that are Strings, Numbers and Booleans.

If I did a text search like this:

```
{ $text: { $search: "false" } }
```

Then it would find all the indexed fields that have false in them even if false was supposed to be for one particular field.

Ideally, I would love to do something like:

```
{ $text: { $search: {color:"blue", happy:True, animals:False} } }
```

where color, happy and animals are already indexed. So it should return back all the documents that contain a combination of these fields; I could run sort on it and have it be sorted based on which documents match the best.

---

Let's say my documents are:

```
{name:"bob", color:"red", happy:True, animals:False}
{name:"smith", color:"blue", happy:False, animals:True}
{name:"joe", color:"blue", happy:True , animals:False}
{name:"jimmy", color:"green", happy:False , animals:True}
```

If I searched:

```
{ $text: { $search: {color:"blue", happy:True, animals:False} } }
```

It would show:

```
{name:"joe", color:"blue", happy:True , animals:False}
{name:"bob", color:"red", happy:True, animals:False}
{name:"smith", color:"blue", happy:False, animals:True}
```

Lines 2 and 3 wouldn't matter in terms of order because both of them match 2/3 of the criteria.

Comment: What you want looks like a *regular* non-text query? Could you elaborate the example a bit?

Comment: Added more to show what I want.